# list indices must be integers, not list how would I change my code to fix this?

Tags: python, indices, conways-game-of-life

Python3 !
I'm working on a conway's game of a life project and I'm trying to pull elements from 2 user inputed lists(coordinates, row/column) to change the cells to alive in a 2d-list. The method I used to try to solve it returned this error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`
is there a another way to do this?(#see commented portion)

here's the function where I turn the cells on

```
def gameBoard(aliveRow, board, aliveCol)
    for i in range(0, len(aliveRow))):
        board[aliveRow[i]][aliveCol[i]] = 'A' #this is where my error takes place
    for i in board:
        print(' '.join(map(str, i)))
    return board
```

I can provide more code if need be.

Comment: What kind of variable are `aliveRow` and `aliveCol`?

Comment: They're both lists, the elements inside of them are integers. @Jasper

Comment: Are you sure? Just do `print(aliveRow[i])` and the same for `Col`. It's the only way this error could occur.

Comment: it printed the rows, but not col...huh

Comment: Thanks for that, makes it a bit easier. @Jasper

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it myself, turns out it was a problem with how I was passing variables function to function.